# How can I plot a line chart based on row rather than column values / using a different x-axis?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am using pandas and matplotlib and have a dataframe using dates as an index. I also have 16 columns/arrays of data with various datapoints at each date.

While I can use df.plot() to plot the various time series I need instead to plot a cross section of data - so at a particular date/row I need to plot a line chart of the values for columns 1-16.

How can I do this?

Thanks

### #

An example of the dataframe is below (it continues spindex_tp_2, 3, 4, and so on until spindex_tp_17). What I am looking to do is produce a line chart / plot using matplotlib that gives me values of spindex_tp_1 to spindex_tp_17 (essentially these values are separate time series running horizontally in my dataframe starting at each date)

[example dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60Bho.png)

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow, could you show an example of your dataframe?

Comment: Thanks; sorry just added an example above